# Linking iOS project as a library

Tags: ios, macos, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

First of all this question is just **theoretical**, I know that is not something you should really do.

I was ordering with it's possible to link an iOS project to use it sources code as a library in a OS X project, since iOS project in **debug** mode produce code for simulator architecture which is the same used in OS X project. I Know that frameworks like UIKit will not be available, but with we link (again I am being theoretical)  with an OSX version of the UIKit?

Comment: It should only take about 20 minutes to try it and find out, just create a tiny iOS library with a single function and try and use it in an OS X app.

Comment: @SausageMachine It's not a library, it's an iOS Application. I tried, I created a iOS Application, and a OS X Application in the same Workspace, but I don't know how to link Application with Application =/

Comment: But your question title says "Linking iOS project as a library", therefore I have no idea what you now mean when you say "its not a library". To create an iOS library you choose File/New/Project/iOS/Framework & Library.

Comment: I have an iOS Application, I want to link it as with was a library project

Comment: If you have an iOS app then you won't be able to link that with anything. If you want to share some code which is within the iOS app then you will first have the split the app into two parts - a library (or framework) and an iOS app that uses that library/framework. Then you might additionally be able to use the iOS library/framework within an OS X app providing the iOS library does not contain anything at all which is specific to the iOS platform, there's probably some Xcode build flags that might need flicking  to get it to work.

Comment: @SausageMachine That was my question! I thought it would not work, I just want to make sure. Thanks for the clarification.